# Post comment time calculation bug on meta

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface

I just observed an issue with posting comments on answers. Even though I posted a comment almost 40 seconds ago, i am getting message "only 1 comment allowed per 15 seconds".  Here is screenshot. Just thought to bring it to your attention.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timer resets every time you trigger it. You can easily keep that up for *hours* if you really tried. :-)

What happens is that if you trigger the lock-out, the timer starts from the start again. If you then try to post a comment within 15 seconds from that message, you get to see it again, and the timer is reset once more. And so on and so forth.

The only way to get by it is to actually wait a full 15 seconds since the last time you saw the big red box. This is thus [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and not a bug.

Comment: This is interesting. Any specific reason to reset timer every time comment link click?

Comment: To discourage people from sitting there an clicking the link over and over again trying to submit their post.  A throttling mechanism isn't effective if it generates *more* requests.

Comment: @Servy: Hmmm make sense. May be message wording need to be more reflective of this design.

Comment: @thinksteep Note the message says `timer reset`. That describes what was happening really well. Each time you click it within the 15 seconds  the timer resets.